# Float, Double, Char, C++ Errors. What is wrong?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, floating-point

I am learning C++, but I ran into an error which I don't understand.

Here is my source code, comments included (personal reference as I am learning.)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 float h; //a float stands for floating point variable and can hold a number that is a fraction. I.E. 8.5
 double j; //a double can hold larger fractional numbers. I.E. 8.24525234
 char f; // char stands for character and can hold only one character (converts to ASCII, behind scenes).
 f = '$';  //char can hold any common symbol, numbers, uppercase, lowerver, and special characters.
 h = "8.5";
 j = "8.56";

 cout << "J: " << j << endl;
 cout << "H: " << h <<endl;
 cout << "F: " << f << endl;

 cin.get();
 return 0;
}
```

I receive the following errors when compiling:

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from
>   'const char [4]' to 'float'
>           There is no context in which this conversion is possible

And

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from
>   'const char [5]' to 'double'
>           There is no context in which this conversion is possible

Can you guys point me in the right direction?
I just learned about const (20 minutes ago maybe) and I don't understand why this previous program isn't working properly.

Comment: Text within double quotes is a *string literal*, which isn't the same as a numeric value.

Comment: This question is such a simple language question any intro tutorial would cover. Dont think it belongs here.

Answer (score 10):

Don't put quotation marks around your floating point values.

```
h = "8.5";
j = "8.56";
```

should be

```
h = 8.5;
j = 8.56;
```

When you type literal values for integral types, like `int`, `short`, etc., as well as floating point types like `float` or `double`, you don't use quotations.

For example:

```
int x = 10;
float y = 3.1415926;
```

You only use double-quotations when you are typing a *string* literal, which in C++ is a null-terminated `const char[]` array.

```
const char* s1 = "Hello";
std::string s2 = "Goodbye";
```

Finally, when you are typing a literal alphabetic or symbolic value for a single character (of type `char`), you can use single quotations.

```
char c = 'A';
```

Answer (score 4):

When assigning to a float or double, you can't wrap the values in quotes.

These lines:

```
h = "8.5";
j = "8.56";
```

Should be:

```
h = 8.5;
j = 8.56;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wrap floating point numbers in "quotes". Anything in quotes is a string (a const char*).

Answer (score 1):

`double` and `float` values should not be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes in the assignements to h an j.